# use awk to edit xml file

Tags: xml, unix, awk

I want to update connector tag attribute of acceptcount & executor in the following way.

```
        <Connector acceptCount="1000" 
                   address="${ajp.listen.address}"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   executor="tomcatThreadPoolupdated1" 
                   maxKeepAliveRequests="15" 
                   port="${ajp.http.port}"  
                   protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol"/>
        <Connector acceptCount="20000" 
                   address="${bio.listen.address}"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   executor="tomcatThreadPoolupdated2"
                   maxKeepAliveRequests="15" 
                   port="${bio.http.port}" 
                   protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" 
                   redirectPort="${bio.https.port}"/>
```

Here is my xml.
if you are giving solution with awk, please explain the solution.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <Server port="${base.shutdown.port}" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
      <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector acceptCount="300" 
                   address="${ajp.listen.address}"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   executor="tomcatThreadPool" 
                   maxKeepAliveRequests="15" 
                   port="${ajp.http.port}"  
                   protocol="org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol"/>
        <Connector acceptCount="200" 
                   address="${bio.listen.address}"
                   connectionTimeout="20000"
                   executor="tomcatThreadPool111"
                   maxKeepAliveRequests="15" 
                   port="${bio.http.port}" 
                   protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" 
                   redirectPort="${bio.https.port}"/>
      </Service>
    </Server>
```

Comment: Assuming you have just one instance of acceptCount with value assigned to it as 200. `sed -i 's/acceptCount="200"/acceptCount="1000"/' config.xml`

Comment: Here in my example i have two acceptCount instances. And different values should get updated in different instances. So, this solution won't solve the issue.

Comment: please help me out.

Comment: How do we know the new values? Are all the new values the same, do you have a list of transpositions?